# How to close pop-up form after successful submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

My website is simple, it has text saying "Click here" , that upon clicking
will open a modal-type contact form in the center of the screen.

Currently when this form is submitted, it delays 1 second, then calls on submit.php
to send the data to my email.

Instead of redirecting to submit.php, I'd like to remain on the same page and simply
close the pop-up contact form.

So it should go like this:

**Click "Click here"** > **Fill in details in pop-up form** > **Click submit** > **Form submits after 1 second and then closes completely.** (No re-direct)

You can view my demo site [here.](http://taskbasket.net/public/demo4.html)

**Here is the form HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin">
 <h1>On submit, this window should close</h1> 

        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" />
       <div class="antispam">
       <br /><input name="url" type="hidden" /></div>
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Write away!" required></textarea>

<button id="flybutton">
            <p>Submit here</p>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path>
            </svg>

        </button>
</form>
```

You can see that the form id is "contactform" and the button id is "flybutton"

The following scripts use this data to currently, delay 1 seccond, submit the form and then
redirect to submit.php.

Instead, I need it to delay 1 second, submit the form, and then close the popup window (and black background).

Currently I have a script that will close the form via Escape key, so perhaps this could be implemented somehow?
I feel that my scripts just need to be combined somehow.

Here are the scripts I have:

**1 second delay + submit form**

```
<script>
        var $btn = $('#flybutton');
        $("#contactform").validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                fly(form);
            }
        });

        $btn.on('fliyingEnd', function (e, form) {
            form.submit();
        })

        function fly(form){

            $btn.toggleClass('clicked');
            $btn.find('p').text(function(i, text) {
                return text === "Fire!" ? "Fire!" : "Fire!";
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                $btn.trigger('fliyingEnd', [form]);
            }, 1000);

        }
    </script>
```

**Close form box (#login-box) and black background (#mask) via escape key:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#mask").fadeOut(300);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#login-box").fadeOut(300);
    }
});
</script>
```

**Another user helped with this script so I don't know it's purpose:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.login-window').click(function() {

            //Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});
// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.closest, #mask').bind('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Can you please tell me which code to edit in order to get the functionality I need?

I couldn't get jsFiddle working but [here's my demo site again](http://taskbasket.net/public/demo4.html)

**UPDATE:**
I've incorporated AJAX, but am having an issue. Specifically, the form submits but it **STILL** redirects.

Included this underneath my form

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

and here is the script.. how do I make NO re-direct?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#contactform").submit(function(event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
            $("#result").html('');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('An error occurred');
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In order not to "refresh" the page, you need to use an AJAX call - which will make a request and return a response without navigating away from the current page. You can find out more here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . A standard form POST (what you are doing currently) always requires a page reload - you could always reload the same page..

Comment: Can you offer a solution, Carl? Anything would help at this point. In the meantime I'll look into AJAX. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solid link here that should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php/14217926#14217926

Comment: Good, that looks like the sort of thing I had in mind :)

Comment: I updated my original question because I'm having a slight AJAX problem. Near the bottom of the question you'll see "Update". Can you see the problem? It's still re-directing to submit.php even though AJAX says it sent successfully. Perhaps some code should be removed from my original scripts?? (It's saying "Success" even if some fields are empty too)

Comment: Try removing the form.submit fron here: 
        $btn.on('fliyingEnd', function (e, form) {
            form.submit();
        })

Comment: Works, thanks man. I noticed though, once the form completes.. if I reopen it, it will automatically RESEND the completed form, so I'll be getting another email. Is there a way to reset the form fields after submission?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that is called now one second after the user hits submit:

```
$btn.on('fliyingEnd', function (e, form) {
        form.submit();
    })
```

You want to get rid of the screen darkening (the mask) and the login popup after the form is submitted, so simply add in the two pieces of code to fade those elements out:

```
$btn.on('fliyingEnd', function (e, form) {
    form.submit();
    $('#mask').fadeOut(300);
    $("#login-box").fadeOut(300);   
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that IS successfully removing the popup and black background, but the form is still submitting to submit.php. I need no redirect to occur

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#a.login-window').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I added this code within script tags  outside of the other scripts, and there seems to be *no* change. The form still redirects to submit.php. I don't think my popup window is an actual modal though, I may be wrong. Perhaps that's why the code won't work? I need the form data to be submitted TO submit.php, but remain on the ORIGINAL page, while closing the form + black background (#mask)

Answer (score 0):

So if I got you right you want to send data to your server without redirecting across documents. You should have a look at the javascript `XMLHttpRequest`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

So, I would do something like:

```
function submit(){
  var contactform=$("#contactform");
  var formdata=new FormData(contactform); //create a js FormData object
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

```
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    // do something here (this is an event handler that is invoked a few times during uploading/downloading process)
  }
  xhr.open("POST","submit.php");
  xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

then you can embed this like in @Zach Sandlers answer

```
$btn.on('fliyingEnd', function (e, form) {
    submit(); // here you send the data to the server
    $('#mask').fadeOut(300);
    $("#login-box").fadeOut(300);   
})
```

WARNING: braincompiled code! may contain syntax errors!

hope that helped

Comment: I'm not sure we're understanding each other. When a user submits the form, I want the form data to be sent TO submit.php but not redirecting. It should remain on the same original page, while also closing the form (#login-box) and black area (#mask). I want to receive the email with form data, while also not redirecting the user away from the main page (demo4.html)

Comment: the javascript XMLHttpRequest supports a few methods like GET and POST. so you use the POST method to send the data inside the form to your php script. this does not trigger any redirect. I'm sorry I can't help you with your #login-box and #mask since I'm not experienced in CSS

Answer (score -1):

I tried your demo link and in submit.php you are storing data(i am guessing) and displaying msg

```
Thank you for contacting us.

We will get back to you within 24 hours.


Go Back
```

Instead of this msg redirect page to demo4.html 
using php function. `header('Location: '.demo4.html);`

If you upload submit.php i will give more details.

Comment: So you're saying I should redirect to submit.php, and then redirect BACK to demo4.html? I'm looking for *no* redirects, not 2!  I need the form data to be submitted TO submit.php, but remain on the ORIGINAL page, while closing the form + black background (#mask).